# Does this mantra in Rig Veda VII.76.4 indicate that earlier mandals were heard in ancient period?

Tags: rig-veda

Rig Veda [VII.76.4](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07076.htm) says as follows:

> They were the Gods’ **companions at the banquet**, the **ancient sages** true
> to Law Eternal. The Fathers found the light that lay in darkness, and
> with effectual words begat the Morning.

This particular mantra refers ancient sages as the **companions of Gods**.

Can we infer from this mantra that the seers, who heard the mantras in earlier Mandalas (**upto 6th Mandala**) of Rig Veda, belong to **ancient age**?

Comment: This is Griffiths translation. Griffiths translation has many errors.

Comment: Please provide your translation. @Swami Vishwananda

Comment: You don't even need to infer it, because it literally says it.